# nfs-kernel-server does not start after reboot

Tags: raspbian, nfs

After installing the nfs server it does not run. After manually sztarting the rpcbind and nfs-kernel-server service everything works fine, but after a reboot it is again not running.

Answer (score 2):

After evaluating tons of answers and threads about this topic I found a quite simple solution.

The problem is that the rpcbind service is not started. This can be achieved just by adding the correct dependencies for the `nfs-kernel-server` service.
Add an approipriate drop-in for this service. For example

*/etc/systemd/system/nfs-kernel-server.service.d/10-dep.conf*:

```
[Unit]
  Requires=rpcbind.service
  After=rpcbind.service
```

Now reboot works fine without any strange sleep commands in service scripts.